# Wordpress custom cost calculation email issue

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, custom-wordpress-pages

I wrote a custom code in WordPress to calculated product cost through customer input through form and display the cost and send email to customer and site admin regarding the details.

It is working but when the quantity ends with "0" in webpage its showing correct total price but in email its showing total cost as zero, I also did some debug all debugging showed correct values but still in email its not showing correct total cost.

Please find the code below

```
// Display product order form and handle submission
function display_product_order_form() {
    $cost_calculated = false;

    // Check if the form is submitted
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // Get form data
        $product_type = sanitize_text_field($_POST['product_type']);
        $fabric_type = sanitize_text_field($_POST['fabric_type']);
        $quantity = intval($_POST['quantity']);
        $print_order = isset($_POST['print_order']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['print_order']) : 'None'; // Default to 'None' if not selected

        // Define cost per unit for each product type and fabric type
        $cost_per_unit = array(
            'tshirt' => array(
                'cotton' => 500.00,
                'polyester' => 250.00,
            ),
            'hoodie' => array(
                'cotton' => 700.00,
                'polyester' => 350.00,
            ),
            // Add more products and fabric types as needed
        );

        // Define additional costs for each print option
        $print_option_costs = array(
            'None' => 0.00,
            'Logo' => 10.00,
            'Text' => 5.00,
            // Add more print options and costs as needed
        );

        // Check if the selected product, fabric type, and print option exist
        if (
            isset($cost_per_unit[$product_type]) &&
            isset($cost_per_unit[$product_type][$fabric_type]) &&
            isset($print_option_costs[$print_order])
        ) {
            // Calculate total cost
            $base_cost = $quantity * $cost_per_unit[$product_type][$fabric_type];
            $print_option_cost = $quantity * $print_option_costs[$print_order];
            $total_cost = $base_cost + $print_option_cost;
            $cost_calculated = true;
            ?>

            <div class="result">
                <p>Total Quantity: <?php echo $quantity; ?></p>
                <p>Product Type: <?php echo ucfirst($product_type); ?></p>
                <p>Fabric Type: <?php echo ucfirst($fabric_type); ?></p>
                <p>Print Option: <?php echo $print_order; ?></p>
                <p>Base Cost: ₹<?php echo number_format($base_cost, 2); ?></p>
                <p>Print Option Cost: ₹<?php echo number_format($print_option_cost, 2); ?></p>
                <p>Total Cost: ₹<?php echo number_format($total_cost, 2); ?></p>
            </div>

            <?php
            // Display the form to collect email after viewing the cost
            ?>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>

                <input type="hidden" name="product_type" value="<?php echo $product_type; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="fabric_type" value="<?php echo $fabric_type; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="print_order" value="<?php echo $print_order; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="total_cost" value="<?php echo $total_cost; ?>">

                <input type="submit" name="send_email" value="Send Email">
            </form>
            <?php
        } else {
            // Display an error if the selected product, fabric type, or print option is not found
            echo '<p>Error: Invalid product type, fabric type, or print option selected.</p>';
        }
    } elseif (isset($_POST['send_email'])) {
        // Check if the email form is submitted

        // Get form data
        $customer_email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
        $product_type = ucfirst(sanitize_text_field($_POST['product_type']));
        $fabric_type = ucfirst(sanitize_text_field($_POST['fabric_type']));
        $quantity = intval($_POST['quantity']);
        $print_order = sanitize_text_field($_POST['print_order']);
        $total_cost = number_format(floatval($_POST['total_cost']), 2);

        // Save email to options
        $stored_emails = get_option('stored_emails', array());
        $stored_emails[] = $customer_email;
        update_option('stored_emails', $stored_emails);

        // Send email to customer
        $subject_customer = 'Your Order Details';
        $message_customer = "Thank you for your order!\n\n";
        $message_customer .= "Product Type: $product_type\n";
        $message_customer .= "Fabric Type: $fabric_type\n";
        $message_customer .= "Quantity: $quantity\n";
        $message_customer .= "Print Option: $print_order\n";
        $message_customer .= "Total Cost: ₹" . number_format($total_cost, 2) . "\n";
        wp_mail($customer_email, $subject_customer, $message_customer);

        // Send email to admin
        $admin_email = get_option('admin_email');
        $subject_admin = 'New Order Details';
        $message_admin = "A new order has been placed!\n\n";
        $message_admin .= "Customer Email: $customer_email\n";
        $message_admin .= "Product Type: $product_type\n";
        $message_admin .= "Fabric Type: $fabric_type\n";
        $message_admin .= "Quantity: $quantity\n";
        $message_admin .= "Print Option: $print_order\n";
        $message_admin .= "Total Cost: ₹" . number_format($total_cost, 2) . "\n";
        wp_mail($admin_email, $subject_admin, $message_admin);

        // Display a confirmation message
        echo '<p>Email sent successfully!</p>';
    } else {
        // Display the initial form
        ?>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <label for="product_type">Product Type:</label>
            <select id="product_type" name="product_type">
                <option value="tshirt">T-Shirt</option>
                <option value="hoodie">Hoodie</option>
                <!-- Add more product types as needed -->
            </select>

            <label for="fabric_type">Fabric Type:</label>
            <select id="fabric_type" name="fabric_type">
                <option value="cotton">Cotton</option>
                <option value="polyester">Polyester</option>
                <!-- Add more fabric types as needed -->
            </select>

            <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
            <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" value="1">

            <label for="print_order">Print Option:</label>
            <select id="print_order" name="print_order">
                <option value="None">None</option>
                <option value="Logo">Logo</option>
                <option value="Text">Text</option>
                <!-- Add more print options as needed -->
            </select>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate Cost">
        </form>

        <?php
    }
}

// Create a shortcode to display the form on a page
add_shortcode('product_order_form', 'display_product_order_form');
```

Comment: Hi. Could you please post the code for your `number_format()` and `floatval()` functions? If you were to log the output of `$message_admin` and `$message_customer` immediately before the call to `wp_mail()`, does this output contain correct numbers?